# Is it possible to create custom User Profile Properties using CSOM or SPO PowerShell?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, user-profile-service, csom, user-profile-property

I have not been able to find much information regarding creating custom User Profile Properties via CSOM or SharePoint Online PowerShell.  Is this possible, and if so, how do I go about doing it?

Comment: I have the similar requirement. Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, only read/update operations can be performed to custom properties using CSOM/PowerShell. However, properties still need to be created manually using GUI in SharePoint-online.

Comment: At Present is there any possibility to create a custom User Profile property? Or still this is not possible?

Answer (score -2):

Try with this

Connect to SP online

http://www.lewisroberts.com/2015/04/10/editing-sharepoint-online-user-profiles-with-powershell/

Add new property

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chandru/archive/2011/09/17/powershell-script-to-create-a-new-user-profile-property.aspx

Comment: You should provide content from the links in your answer.  And the second link is not valid for SharePoint Online.

Comment: Although the second link is fantastic for use in on premise environments, I need a CSOM only approach or one that uses SPO friendly PowerShell cmdlets.