# Create custom user profile property in O365 using CSOM

Tags: csom, custom, user-profile-property

I have a requirement in one of my projects to create a `Custom User Property` in the user profile programmatically using `CSOM`.

Is there any mechanism to do so?

Please pour in your thoughts.

Comment: Not sure its possible - http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/166569/is-it-possible-to-create-custom-user-profile-properties-using-csom-or-spo-powers

Comment: If you can use /_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx web service to add the custom property. http://www.sharemuch.com/2012/05/13/dynamically-modify-sharepoint-user-profile-properties-with-jquery/